# Putting images next to answer options

Tags: graphics, lists, enumerate

I am formatting a test for my students, and I'm having trouble making the something like the following happen.

Desired output:

[image: question]

I separately produced the graphs and wrote the following LaTeX code

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{figure}[h]
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{answerA}
      \end{figure}
\item \begin{figure}[h]
          \includegraphics[width=5cm]{answerB}
      \end{figure}
\item \begin{figure}[h]
          \includegraphics[width=5cm]{answerC}
      \end{figure}
\item \begin{figure}[h]
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{answerD}
      \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
```

But I'm getting this instead -

[image: bad output]

My question is, what am I doing wrong? Should I use another package?
I'm currently using inputenc, amsmath, and graphicx for my packages.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`, which creates a float.  Just use the `\includegraphics...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, don't use `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`, which creates a float. Just use the `\includegraphics...`.  Here, I create a macro `\Includegraphics`, to shift it vertically to the proper alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,enumitem}
\newcommand\Includegraphics[2][]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
11. The graph...
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph{*}),leftmargin=.7in]
\item \Includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\item \Includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
\item \Includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
\item \Includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. Thank you!